# Create account test Instagram for API graph messenger instagram standard access

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, instagram-graph-api

For getting the permission of the scope Instagram_manage_messages to "advanced access", Facebook requests a video to show them how to utilize the API Messenger Instagram standard access. For that, we need a page of user test Facebook linked into an Instagram Account.
However, the linked page test with an account IG does not work.
Does someone know how to create a user test Instagram who could be linked into page user test facebook, otherwise the API does not work from user public, So I have trouble showing them the processing of using the API.

Comment: This doesn't work well with actual test user accounts, I would suggest you test with a user that has a role in the app instead.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for your reply, however even with user who has role administrator in app, the result of the API is a data empty, and the support Fb suggested me to use test user